# Continuously reading data from TCP connection using io.ReadFull

Tags: go, io, buffer

I have the following data structure that I expect to read from TCP socket connection, first 4 bytes are a uint32 that describes the length of the payload that follows these 4 bytes. I try to continuously read from a connection using following code:

```
// c is TCP connection
func StartReading(c io.Reader, ok chan bool) {
    // Reader reads first 4 bytes as payload length
    for l, err := getPayloadLength(c); err == nil; {
        //Reader reads the rest of the message
        b, err := readFixedSize(c, l)
        if err != nil {
            ok<- false
            close(ok)
            return
        }
        go process(b, make(chan bool))
    }
    ok<- true
}

func getPayloadLength(r io.Reader) (uint, error) {
    b, err := readFixedSize(r, 4)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return uint(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b)), nil
}

// Read fixed size byte slice from reader
func readFixedSize(r io.Reader, len uint) (b []byte, err error) {
    b = make([]byte, len)
    _, err = io.ReadFull(r, b)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    return
}
```

My expectation is that it will read first four bytes from incoming data, parse it to `l`, and based on parsed value will read consequent `l` bytes. The first read from a connection yields expected results, but in all consequent read iterations, the reader seems to read 4 bytes from the end of the previous message.

By trial and error I ended up with the following code which reads as expected, but I still could not understand why the code above does not work as I expect.

New code:

```
func StartReading(c io.Reader, ok chan<- bool) {
    br := bufio.NewReader(c)
    // Peek into first 4 bytes for payload length
    for lb, err := br.Peek(4); err == nil; {
        // Read length bytes into uint
        l := uint(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(lb))
        b := make([]byte, l + 4)
        _, err := br.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            ok<- false
            return
        }
        //Process from 4th byte
        go process(b[4:], make(chan bool))
    }
    ok<- true
}
```

I do kind of understand why the latter code works, but can't wrap my head around why the first code does not work as expected. I'm quite new to Go, so could someone please explain what happened there?

Comment: The second code is using `Read` which may or may not fill the buffer to the end. Are you sure the second code is working as expected?

Comment: So far it seems to work well. I have also found this answer which suggests the same approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220855/6555251.

Comment: Perhaps create workable playground examples so that developers can look at your running code. That makes it much easier to dig into the line which makes the difference